# How to disable environments tab on github

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a github project [here](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL). Recently a new tab appeared "1 environments". When I open this tab I see a lot of github-pages related information. I had github pages in the past, but they are now disabled.

How to get rid of this tab?

I have tried to delete the `github-pages` branch from the remote:

```
(venv) D:\Programming\ModernGL>git push origin :github-pages
error: unable to delete 'github-pages': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL'
```

I have listed branches and tags with `git ls-remote` I cannot see any `github-pages`.

I have checked, the project settings are properly set.

`Settings / Github Pages / Source` is set to `None`

Comment: Did you figure it out? I noticed the environment tab has gone from your GitHub project

Comment: It is still there. It is only visible to the owner of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may have to do with new set of features that github announced yesterday including Actions